# Checking if value is in list and flag it if is not valid

Tags: python-3.x

I have a string looking like this:

```
DEtypename : APP, DTRAFFIC, HTTP, ALL; DEsocio_citysize : up to 1.999 inhabitants, 2000 inhabitants, 3000+
```

I am trying to write a functions to turn this string to a dictionary(key:DEtypename, DEsocio_citysize) and the corresponding values after the ':'). The file with the string should be in text file. This is the function that turns them into dictionary:

```
def read_lists(in_key):
list_key = []
list_value = []
data_dict = {}
with open('lists', mode='r') as file:
    data = file.readlines()
    for line in data:
        rules = line.split('; ')
        for l in rules:
            key, value = l.split(' : ')
            list_key.append(key)
            list_value.append(value)
            data_dict = dict(zip(list_key,list_value))
        return data_dict[in_key]
```

The next function should read this dictionary and as an input should be the key and a string to look for in the corresponding values for this key.
Something like this, but it returns - "'function' object is not subscriptable"

```
def check_in_list(string, key):
    if string in read_lists[key]:
        return string
    else:
        return string + '_not_valid'

print(check_in_list(input, 'DEtypename'))
```

Now, if the input is "APP" it should return the given input if its 'APPP' should concat the '_not_valid' string. I hope my explanation was clear.

I have decided to change the structure

```
data = input()

def read_ruleset(file_name):
    with open(file_name, mode='r') as file:
        data = file.readlines()
        return data

#print(read_ruleset('lists'))


def read_lists(file_name, in_key, string):
    list_key = []
    list_value = []
    #data_dict = {}
    lists = read_ruleset(file_name)
    print(lists)
    for line in lists:
        rules = line.split('; ')
        for l in rules:
            key, value = l.split(' : ')
            list_key.append(key)
            list_value.append(value)
            data_dict = dict(zip(list_key,list_value))
            if string is None:
                return string or '_not_valid'
            else:
                if string in data_dict[in_key]:
                    return string
                else:
                    return string + '_not_valid'



print(read_lists('lists', 'DEsocio_citysize', data))
```

Comment: Is your dictionary example above 2 keys, or 1?

Comment: Calling a function requires parens, not square brackets. Change `read_lists[key]` to `read_lists(key)`.

Comment: Thank you @glibdud, this worked. I have one question. Is it possible to merge the two functions into one? So my inputs for the function to be the file name, the key and the value I am searching for.

Comment: I don't see why not. If you're having trouble with a particular part of that implementation, I'd recommend asking a new question and showing how far you got and what exactly you're stuck on.

Comment: I've edited the the post. I am getting KeyError on data_dict[in_key] and on the print I cant use the key as a input. @glibdud can help on this?